# MongoDB: Checking if nested array contains sub-array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a use case where the database is modelled like this:

```
name: XYZ
gradeCards: [{
  id: 1234, // id of the report card
  comments: ['GOOD','NICE','WOW']
}, {
  id: 2345,
  comments: ['GOOD','NICE TRY']
}]
```

Now, I have a query that I would like to query the schema as follows:

I would be given a list of ids and values.
For example: the given list is as follows:

```
[{
  id: 1234,
  comments: ['GOOD','NICE']
},{
  id: 2345,
  comments: ['GOOD']
}]
```

In short the ID should be matching and the comments should be a sub-array of the comments array for that id and also, all the conditions specified in the array should be matched, so it should be an AND condition on all the conditions provided.

I was able to get to this query, but it matches all of the elements in the comments array, I want that id should be exactly matched and comments should be a subarray.

For matching all elements in comments array:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({arr:{
    $all: [{
        id:1234,
        comments:['GOOD','NICE','WOW']
    },{
        id:2345,
        comments:['GOOD','NICE TRY']
    }]
 }})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `$all` with `$elemMatch` to match on the query conditions.

```
db.collection.find({
    gradeCards: {
        $all: [{
            "$elemMatch": {
                id: 1234,
                comments: {
                    $in: ['GOOD', 'NICE']
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$elemMatch": {
                id: 2345,
                comments: {
                    $in: ['GOOD']
                }
            }
        }, ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain why we require $elemMatch? I get the use of $in.

Comment: You are welcome. `$elemMatch` matches on atleast one document in the array  which has both `id` and `comments` matching query values and `$all`  with `$elemMatch` to match both the documents on their respective query criteria. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide some idea on if we want an OR condition instead of AND condition of all the specified array inputs? Why doesn't simply replacing $all with $in and removing $elemMatch not work?

Comment: You have to use the `db.collection.find({
    "gradeCards": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$or": [
                { id: 1234,  comments: {$in:['GOOD','NICE'] }},
                { id: 2345,  comments: {$in:['BAD']}}
            ]
        }
    }
})` for `OR`. You are expecting operators to work in certain way which they necessarily may not. Please read about them.